# I'm banned, and editing my questions didn't help. Now what can I do?

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes, account-suspension, post-ban

My account has been question-banned for two days. Per the ban info link's suggestion, I tried to edit the questions which were down-voted. I found that my questions were not up-voted after I edited the questions — which they should have been, according to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers/86998#86998) — but "ended in smoke."

I am tired of this, and now I want to delete my account and start a new one. Is it possible to start a new account?

Also, here's something I wondered after I edited my down-voted questions: do the voters who down-voted see the changes? If not, it's really pretty unlikely that other users will see and up-vote my questions in the near — or far! — future, as Stack Overflow is a place to ask questions and there are many questions!

Comment: If you want a better response to your questions, I would recommend not adding 'please help' kind of nonsense to the end of your questions. Just ask your question.

Comment: okay.Thanks.I will remember it.

Comment: [ehm this is not an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11557343/644450) :) It is more like a comment and such posts should be avoided :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the answer to the question you linked to:

> ### Can I simply create a new account?
>
> No. The automatic ban is at [a lower level than
>   account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72180/clarify-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account-error/76167#comment-174366).

Creating a new account to work around the question-asking ban is generally not an acceptable practice here.

Give this a little more time, and try contributing some valuable answers. Two days is not a long period for a few questions to gain upvotes, so it might take a little longer.

Also, you have two self-deleted questions, which works against the question ban heuristics. If you'd like, I could undelete those, but you'd need to edit them into shape afterward.

Comment: Sure sir.Go ahead and un-delete them.I would work hard to make them worth up-vote!!

Comment: Also i would like to know do the voters who down voted see the changes when the down voted questions are edited?

Comment: @SubirAdhikari - Those questions are now undeleted and you should see them within your profile. You might want to edit them quickly so that they don't attract other downvotes. For your other question, downvoters are not currently notified as to changes in the questions they have voted on.

Comment: It would be very kind of you sir,if you please review the deleted questions which you un-deleted recently, and suggest me what may be the reasons it attracted down-votes because this is the reason I deleted them and my account was banned soon after!

Comment: @BradLarson The "try contributing some valuable answers" bit doesn't work. It won't help getting the ban lifted! Yes, I know the answer that you linked to says so, but it isn't true. I tried to get the info in that answer corrected, but all my attempts so far have been in vain.

Comment: @MrLister - It didn't work for your Meta account because you got so heavily downvoted there was no coming back from that. Unless you're accusing the devs of misrepresenting things, this should work in cases where the user is just over the threshold to trigger the ban, like is the case here.

Comment: @BradLarson But do you realise that this is the first actual answer I've received about my ban? My answer to the "canonical" question was deleted and none of my emails have gotten any replies. To top that, answers I deleted myself began to get undeleted, flags I raised were ignored, bounties I started got refunded, etc, as if I didn't exist any more. So this is the first. Also, this is the first time that I hear it's possible to get "so heavily downvoted there was no coming back". Don't you think the "official" answer needs to mention this?

Comment: @MrLister: The canonical answer states fairly clearly that, while improving your posts may lift the ban, there is no guarantee that the ban will actually be lifted.

Comment: If you spoof your IP address or connect from a different IP address, you can create a new account and abandon the banned account. You can also asks questions as a "userXXXXXXX" without registering on SE, but SE will track your IP address and grab other things such as cookies, etc. so delete all cookies before visiting SE sites.

Comment: @FrankComputer - Cookies are not currently tracked for any of this, and in fact a [suggestion to use cookies in this manner](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113394/implement-some-form-of-browser-fingerprinting-to-help-suss-out-socks) was met with significant opposition. Also, is it really helpful to suggest that people spoof their IP addresses so that they can do something that is against the rules of the site?