# I am blocked from asking questions. Cleaning up, but only got 5 edits a day. What to do?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, post-ban

I got blocked from asking questions in Stack Overflow and I can see why, as many of my questions are clearly duplicates, bad formulated or bad in other ways as I didn't do my research well enough and didn't have enough experience on the subject before asking.

So now I want to clean it all up, which means flag the duplicates and edit the questions so they'll be easier to understand and learn from. But I only have a limited number of edits each day, and I can't find any way to get in contact with a moderator so I can get more edits. I also could need some suggestions on how to improve my questions.

Comment: You can also contribute answer other questions and make (constructive) edits to questions/answers from other users.

Comment: Thanks. Will I be able to post questions automaticly after improving myself?

Comment: Yes, see [What can I do when getting "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997) The process is fully automatic.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. It depends. According to [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140839/im-banned-and-editing-my-questions-didnt-help-now-what-can-i-do/140845#comment397972_140845), if one of your questions is downvoted heavily enough, you will never ever be able to post again, no matter how much rep you gain.

Comment: @MrLister: I don't think that was meant literally, but I can imagine there are situations that are almost impossible to overcome if the negative weight is heavy enough. Note the "almost" there.

Comment: Also, the action of editing your posts has no effect all by itself. You've got to get the downvoters to return to your question and retract their downvotes. And this is the hard part, because downvotes are anonymous and you won't know who to contact.

Comment: I don't think my questions have so many down wotes, I would have seen it if they had? But not so many up's eighter. I think the banning is mainly because of duplicates and because I deleted many of my own questions when I read them later and saw that they were not very good..

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just don't want to give the OP any false hope. There was no "almost" in my case, and I did gain hundreds of rep by answering questions, but it never helped. And the other hints in the "What can I do" answer didn't help either: I couldn't get people to upvote my questions again, staff never answered my emails, etc. So I've given up now.

Comment: Referring to MrLister's last-but-one comment: Or get others to upvote, it's the score that counts. +10/-10 isn't worse than ±0.

Comment: @KristofferBilek The deleting is probably a big part of it. You get banned if you have too many deleted questions.

Comment: Ok, then that's it I guess. Deleting some bad duplicate questions which also are very connected to my own case so it's not helpful for others, I would think that was a good thing, but then I'll just edit/flag them instead..

Comment: Indeed, I feel @MrLister is right about editing not giving much hope at all. Still, it was a Stack Exchange employee who added that *"Before you do anything else, fix your existing posts!"* to the FAQ in December 2011. So I assume downvotes (or the net score) have a much bigger impact than earning additional upvotes on other posts. Just guessing though.

Comment: @Daniel, any reference for your *"it's the score that counts. +10/-10 isn't worse than ±0"*?

Comment: @MrLister: I am sorry your experience has been so discouraging. But you are but one example, and since you obviously are not using the same account anymore (I see recent questions and answers on your SO account), I cannot check for myself what your situation was. Thus, I am not sure your case can be generalized so easily.

Comment: @Arjan Memory. May be fooling me of course. Trying to find a citation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are right of course, generalizations are always bad. But you were generalising too, above: the OP asked if he's be able to post again and you said yes. As if simply improving one's posts and gaining new rep points would be a guarantee. I can say from experience that's not always the case!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, and yes, I do have two accounts now. And I dread the day that the accounts will be merged...

Comment: On the other hand, @Martijn, have we seen other examples? Sure, a few around here were successful lifting the ban, but I guess we'll never know what caused the balance to trip to the other side. (And mostly, *I think*, getting some attention here and hence getting some pity upvotes helped a lot, for rescuable folks who did not have —deleted— heavily downvoted posts. *I think* editing has not changed a lot for them, but of course I don't know either.) (As for MrLister's ban, things were even more different, as that was a post ban on Meta, where voting is supposed to be different.)

Comment: @Arjan: With the process secret, and offenders reluctant to share their experiences, we are not likely to learn of many. Speculation and conjecture on the basis of *one* vocal case is not going to make things clearer. I rather go with the official information we *do* have that indicates there is a possibility for redemption.

Comment: @MartijnPieters if you're interested, check details at [older account of Mr Lister](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/174847/discount-gucci-unicorns)

Comment: That's only part of the story nowadays, @gnat.

Comment: @Martijn, but then where does the official information say "Yes" to *"Will I be able to post questions automaticly after improving myself?"* I fully agree with MrLister there: we mortals just don't know that.

Comment: @Arjan well the part of the story I am able to see, looks pretty sad

Comment: You deleted a lot of your own questions.  That can be the cause of the ban.  I have undeleted them; see if that helps.  In future, its better to leave them open, or answer them yourself, rather than delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the limit of 5 posts per day set for your own post you can edit, there is few you can do. Not even moderators can raise that limit for users, or for a single user.
In the case your posts are radically changed by another user, and somebody notices it, the edit would be immediately reverted.

Editing a question could help if your question has been closed, and it doesn't have any answer.
In that case, after you edited the question, you can flag for moderation attention, asking to re-open your question. I am not sure if moderators would re-open your question in all the cases, but that it could help if it gets up-votes, and somebody provides an answer you accept.

In the case there are answers, it is probable that changing a question that has been closed would not help for re-opening it.
Radically changing the question would invalidate the given answers, and the moderator who would re-open your question is not going to delete the existing answers that don't have anymore meaning. This would require a moderator to evaluate which answers don't have anymore sense, and this is something moderators are not called for.

If you really need to change your questions to re-open them, you have the limit of 5 posts per day. Alternatively, users with a question ban are usually said to gain reputation by answering to questions. I cannot say if this effectively works, as I have never had a question ban.

Comment: Thanks for informing and logic answer. In my case I had deleted some questions because I had posted many very similar questions, and many of my questions were generally bad in different ways so I don't know what made the ban in the first place, but now it went back to normal after I did some cleaning up (not done yet) so like the FAQ says: start by cleaning up your own questions!

Answer (score 7):

To others experiencing the same thing: if you make a little effort changing what made you banned in the first place and avoid getting like a million downvotes before you do something about it (then you'll have one hell of a job to do), the chances are good for getting back in the game in no time. There is no reason to give up. If you lose a job or get a warning you don't just lay down on the ground to die or what.

Comment: Ah, I remember, it's the [summer of tough love](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/), right? ;)

Comment: Right:P ... hehe